# Two folder each file open based on date difference & perform set of code

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, datetime

I have two folders containing a set of Files (The number of Files will be dynamic always). For each First Folder file is open I want to run a set of code for the second file if the date rule that is calculated below is within it or Minimum & if two minimum dates then higher date will be used

Example as stated below in the image

[image]

Comment: Please paste your samples and code as text, it's easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20list#os.listdir) to get the content of your folders, and then use [os.getctime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime) to get the creation date (change date for unix systems) of the files/folders. If you want to get the dates from the filename, you can just use string operations on the result of os.listdir .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).